# Show modal dialog on page load

Tags: javascript, html

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhi009ihba/RU5m8/): this is the link to my problem.

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">close</a>
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want this modal box to open automatically when the page loads.

Comment: You've tagged this as jQuery but there is none in your Fiddle. Are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("openModal").style.opacity = 1;
}
```

it won't work in jsfiddle but it should be fine in your page

Answer (score 0):

seems like, initially the ModalBox is hidden, probably using

```
display:hidden
```

then

```
$(documnet).ready(function{
   $('#openModal').css('display','block')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `:target` selector, you can just set the window location on page load:

```
window.location.href = "#openModal";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7LcRN/

In your implementation of the script (jsFiddle automatically adds an onLoad event for you), you will need to add an event to the page load to trigger this:

```
<body onload="window.location.href = '#openModal'">
    // Your HTML
</body>
```

Or using addEventListener:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    window.location.href = "#openModal";
});
```

I've also removed all references to your `load()` function, which doesn't exist. Also, `<div>` does not have the `onload` event.

Answer (score 0):

(damn this `:target` css lol)

The only methods that has `onload` are :Iframe,img , body. `div` doesn't has it.

Also - you have no function `load` and you have no function when clicking the div.

What you want is : to remove the `load` function since it doesn't exists and add this :

```
$(function(){

    $("a:first")[0].click(); //simulate the behaviour which will 
                             //trigger that css `.modalDialog:target{...}`
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RU5m8/10/

Answer (score 0):

Trigger click as the page loads...

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
    $("a")[0].trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do two changes in your jsfiddle code

step : 1) you add and jquery version form drop down.

step : 2) add bellow code in your code

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $('a').get(0).click();
      });
```

and see it is working as you want and it also available in updated js link is
"http://jsfiddle.net/RU5m8/11/"

i hope it helpfull to you